# Firebase show posts for following users

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I am using FirebaseRecyclerAdapter and I am trying to show the post for following users only so I couldn't get the correct query for that the query that I need is at the pic describe:

[image]

I am currently using this method:

```
mDatabase= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Posts");

FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Getting_Posts, PostViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Getting_Posts, PostViewHolder>(
            Getting_Posts.class, R.layout.post_card_design, PostViewHolder.class, mDatabase) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(final PostViewHolder viewHolder, final Getting_Posts model, int position) {

            final String Post_Key = getRef(position).getKey();

        }
    };mPostList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
};
```

this method shows all post but I need to show post for following user

So I need the query that must I use it so please any help.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
mDatabase= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Posts").orderByChild("UID").equalTo("UID TO SEARCH FOR");

FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Getting_Posts, PostViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Getting_Posts, PostViewHolder>(
            Getting_Posts.class, R.layout.post_card_design, PostViewHolder.class, mDatabase)
```

Answer (score 0):

I also developed an app little bit similar to Instagram and used the conditions which you are looking for,
So first of all fetch all your followings from firebase into an ArrayList.And than  make conditions fetching posts as

```
if(followeinglist.contains(UID FROM POST)){mArrayListPost.add(YOUR POST);}
```

and find followings as

```
 DatabaseReference userPostRef = mDatabase.child(KeyTAG.TAG_FOLLOWINGS).child(YOUR USER ID).orderByChild("userid");
    if (userPostRef == null) {
    } else {
        userPostRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Iterable<DataSnapshot> children = dataSnapshot.getChildren();


                for (DataSnapshot child : children) {

                            followeinglist.add(child.getKey());
                                       }
                mAdapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: How can I get the following from database into Arraylist

Comment: Sorry brother, but I couldn't know how to make it, I will add my activity and you can give me the fully answer, because I didn't know how to use the method